# Excel Macros 2007: How can I Bold the Row if a number is in Column A?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

My long list of data has numbers in Column A, but in random rows. How can a macro be written to find a number in Column A and then bold the corresponding data in that row?

I know if I record my actions as a macro it's not going to work. Any help or code would be really appreciated.

Many thanks

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This WikiHow article](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Conditional-Formatting-in-Excel) explains how to do conditional formatting in detail.

Comment: +1: Conditional formatting is the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: Hadn't thought of CF. Tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just select the entire column by clicking the column name and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>? Or does the column have mixed content types?

Comment: Not all the rows in Column A have numbers, and it's only those that with numbers that I need to make bold.